# Prevent Entry of duplicate data to MongoDB Database when using Node Js Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing a Node JS System using the MongoDB database. I'm using mongoose for ORM. I want to insert new data into the database and lets the system lets us know that if the data are already created, there will be no data creation will be done.
Let say I have a data in a collection `Timetable` which is

```
Subject=English
Classroom=6 Usaha
timeslot=10.00
Day=Monday
```

How can I prevent a system to create a data to the database which has exactly the exact value with the one that i mention? I thinking about writing a schema which will be like this

```
subject: {

type:String,
unique:true,
}

Classroom: {

type:String,
unique:true,

}

timeslot: {

type:String,
unique:true,

}

Day: {

type:String,
unique:true,

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will simply need to create a new a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) at the [schema level](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) for this like:

```
yourSchema.index({
  subject: 1, Classroom: 1, timeslot: 1, Day: 1
}, { unique: true });
```

Please make sure this index filed names and schema field names are exact same.

Also, `1` after the field names here specifies an index that orders items in ascending order.

This will prevent a system to create a data to the database which has exactly the exact value with the one that you have mentioned.

Comment: Do i have to create anothe file in my model folder or just write on exisitng model?

Comment: You can do it in same model only after creating the schema.